# Android - Debug build is consuming less memory than the release one

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on an android app(kotlin, jetpack compose + XML) where the debug version consumes 30mb after installation and the release version consumes 120mb after installation. I did not enable minify because I'm trying to understand what's happening why the release build consumes so much memory. I checked the memory usage after installation on google play console and it seems like of the 120mb memory usage 70 mb are used by "Optimised DEX" files.
Can you please help me with some tips, why the debug version consumes less memory(both debug version and prod have the same features), where can I find some decent documentation about optimised dex files?

Tried to find related questions about this issue, nothing found, I found someone saying that debug build is optimised to run faster and is using resources and code accessible by the device installed on, so I tried to build the apk and install it via ADB, same result, the app is consuming 3 times less memory than the prod build. Now I'm trying to decide if enabling minify is worth for this kind of big project.

Comment: Why would you not enable minification for a production release, *especially* for a big project? I don't know where it's clearly documented, but it makes logical sense that performance optimized files would take more space because of redundancies. If you enable minifcation and use App Bundles instead of APKs, you'll probably see the size drop below 30MB in practice. Just guessing, and it depends on the project.